# trying to get a bot to send a photo using pytelegrambotapi but i keep do it just once

Tags: py-telegram-bot-api

I want my telegram bot written on Python using pyTelegramBotAPI to send a picture on command /photo
If i try this code I will recive photo just once, no matter how many times I trigger ths command

```
photo = open('all_path/sudoku_1.png', 'rb')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
def send_photo(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,photo)
```

To receive it once more I have to restart the bot or do like that

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
def send_photo(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('all_path/sudoku_1.png', 'rb'))
```

This is uncomfortable, can I do something else?
And I'm new to Python and don't know much yet
Help please

Answer (score 0):

I don't see all your code, but maybe you didn't use `bot.infinity_polling()`??

It runs your bot until force stop, like `while(True)` loop.